# glibc compilation system

Tags: compilation, makefile, glibc

i have implemented a custom hash table implementation. The source code is to be included inside glib as a separate directory 'hash' placed along with the existing ones like malloc, signals etc. Can any body please tell me what needs to be done to make the glibc make system aware of additional hash directory. Any pointer will be helpful.

Thanks,
Kapil

Answer (score 1):

replying in the hope that some day some one may be bebefited with it:

```
subdir  := hash             # dirctory name
headers := hash.h
routines = hash            # name of the C file
include ../Rules
```

Thats it!!!